# Outlook Add-in . API is not supported in this platform

Tags: server, outlook, add-in, hosted

Is there a minimum requirement for a server hosting an outlook add-in? I am trying to use SSO for our Outlook Add-in and the error "API is not supported in this platform." is being returned when using the Add-in hosted in a Windows Server 2016.

Interestingly, when the same Outlook Add-in is hosted in a Windows Server 2019, the error is not happening and SSO is working ok.

The part of the code throwing this error is on this line:
let tokenData = await OfficeRuntime.auth.getAccessToken({ allowSignInPrompt: true});

Thanks in advance.